# Slack Github integration

Tags: github, integration, slack

I am integrating Github with Slack to receive updates such as pull request, issues, commits etc. But when I subscribe to Github repo it shows all the notifications from all devs whenever they make changes. I only want notifications when I or one more dev on my team makes any changes to that repo. Is this something which can be done?